# PM2 as a service on Windows (private server)

Tags: node.js, server, pm2

I'm facing an issue when using PM2 to keep my application alive on Windows. The problem is that when I log out of my user or the server, PM2 also closes, and consequently, my process shuts down as well. How can I solve this? It's worth noting that the server is on a private network, and I can't download files or packages within it. I would appreciate any help.

Does anyone know how to deal with this?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/985734/how-do-i-run-a-windows-command-as-a-service Is this helpful?

Comment: Hi, no, this solution is not working for me, i need to run PM2 as a windows service independent from my user

Comment: That link seems to explicitly describe how to do just that using multiple methods. Did those not work? The first answer specifically says task scheduler can be used to run a task at boot as a specific user.

Answer (score 0):

First verify you have installed pm2 globally with this command: `npm i -g pm2`

Second install one of these packa from npm: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=pm2%20windows%20service

This one for example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nick92/pm2-windows-service

after executing instructions, you will have a windows service that can restart PM2 after a reboot or a user deconnexion.